# How to use `click` in a shortcut? (Run a service when clicking a link)

Tags: automator, shortcut, services, shortcut-menu, click

Is it possible to run an Automator service with an alternate click, e.g. `⌘ + ⇧ + Click`? This kind of combination is built into browsers with `⌘ + Click` typically opening a link in a new tab.

I have a service for handling links. Right now I can right click the link, pick services from the context menu, and then select my service. I'd rather not navigate the menu. Is there a way I can harness `Click` when making a shortcut?

A half-option is to right click the link, click elsewhere to close the dialog, and then press the keyboard shortcut, but this is cumbersome. (I'd be happy enough if I had to right click and then do a shortcut, but this seems to not work without clicking away.)

I've internet sleuthed with enough search strategies that I think this may not be possible but am hoping I'm wrong and simply a careless querier!

Comment: Sans the use of a third-party utility (if one exists), or one you write on your own, that has the ability to monitor keypress and mouse clicks and the ability to intercept these events to then do something, I do not believe what your are asking is doable.

Answer (score -1):

## BetterTouchTool

You can use better touch tool to remap your clicks on your trackpad or mouse. Here is a screenshot of the rule I created. It copies the url from the hyperlink and sends this to a shell script, where you can handle it as you wish.

[image: BetterTouchTools Mapping Rules]

The last line actions, "Execute Shell Script" has this configuration:

[image: Script Action Configuration]

This just runs an executable script and pastes in the url as its argument. If you don't want to use a bash/zsh script you can use applescript or javascript or python or perl or whatever you are comfortable with by changing the launch path.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding but this seems to be a solution to simulating clicking. Instead, I'm looking to manually click while holding down a key for added functionality

Comment: @Unrelated I changed the answer so it provides you a solution to your problem. If you are using a mouse (not a built in trackpad) you could use Karabiner-Elements instead. If you'd rather go that route I can write it up, but this BetterTouchTools route will work whether you are using a mouse or the trackpad so that seems ideal.